# Sed command to change a specific cronjob

Tags: sed

I want to modify my cronjob by using sed cmd

my cronjob is as below

```
* * * * * root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh
```

i used sed to modify my line so i tape the cmd below

```
sed -i 's|* * * * * root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh|* * * * * root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh > /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/logs/config_updater.log|' /etc/cron.d/filebeat-cybersoc-3
```

i dont get the result as expected
i got this :

```
* * * * * * * * * root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh > /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/logs/config_updater.log
```

instead of :

```
* * * * * root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh > /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/logs/config_updater.log
```

Comment: `*` is a quantifier (0 or more times),  must be escaped `\*` or in a character set `[*]` to match the character `*`, also `^` anchor may be use to match the start of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking the problem - all you need is (assuming that you only have that one line in the file)

```
 sed -i 's|$|> /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/logs/config_updater.log|' /etc/cron.d/filebeat-cybersoc-3
```

where `s|$|` searches for the end of line and then you just attach the redirect.

As Nahuel pointed out in the comment above: `*` is a quantifier in regex, so that won't work without escaping.

Otherwise:

```
sed -i 's|^\* \* \* \* \* root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh|* * * * * root /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/config_updater.sh > /apps/filebeat-cybersoc-3/logs/config_updater.log|' /etc/cron.d/filebeat-cybersoc-3
```